# Are automatic assault rifle useless in current conflict?

Tags: weapons

This question seems a bit weird, but actually in most of western armies, soldiers are trained to shoot with semi automatic mode. Since most of the contact with the enemy occurs at long range, it's much more accurate. Even in CQB you never use automatic fire. So why individual weapon ( I'm not talking about LMG like the m249 or the FN Minimi ) still have this possibility ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as written, it's not about history but is questioning current military procurement policy.

Answer (score 2):

Summary from [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-militaries-use-assault-rifles-when-the-full-auto-feature-is-rarely-ever-used)

- Multiple targets at short range
- When a small team encounters a much larger enemy, they execute a breaking-contact maneuver.
- only costs a few dollars per weapon to add that capability to the rifle. Just doing a cost/benefit analysis will tell you that dramatically enhancing the capabilities of the rifle for such a small additional cost would always be worth it.
- situations like CQB (close quarters battle, clearing rooms) where the distances are often just a few feet, don't require accuracy. They require half a dozen rounds pumped into the bad guy in a half a second, because you don't want to worry about if you hit him or not, if he's dead or just wounded, if he's wounded can he get up and shoot my friends or detonate a bomb vest because things are happening fast
- Another reason is that under all the stress and fatigue of combat it's actually pretty damned hard to maintain the accuracy you achieve on the rifle range.
- ambush situations

Comment: Even for multiple target at short range ( below 25m ) we were told to shoot in semi automatic mode. It's the same for the breaking contact maneuver ( I guess you refer to the tube ? ).

Comment: Ambushes and breaking engagements, definitely. I would also add covering fire.The large volume of fire intimidates the enemy and can often give the appearance of a much larger force. This does require that fire is opened almost simultaneously by the entire unit, but is devastating in terms of morale and will (temporarily) stop any infantry movement in the area being fired upon, giving time to break contact or vector in fire support. It may even intimidate the enemy into breaking off and falling back to their previous positions.